# Trying to access JSON object's array's children: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get the `Description` array from a JSON object, loop it, and return it to the user.

I have JSON code in a format sort of like this:

```
[
   {
      "FoodNumber":"4567421",
      "FoodName":"Banana",
      "FoodCode":"110",
      "DocumentDate":"19991223",
      "ArrivalDate":"20020820",
      "BogusField":"1241231",
      "WhereFound":"In the jungle, man",
      "DateEaten":"I dunno, every day?",
      "Description":
      [
         "A vicious predator, the ravenous Banana stalks the jungles forcing monkeys to eat it",
         "Monkeys think it's food, but it's really a parasite"
      ]
   }
]
```

This is inside of ajax `success: function (z)`. I parse it using `var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);`, and that allows me to access each individual data type, except `Description`. I need to be able to loop through that text array. I am currently using this jQuery code, and it works for all except `Description`:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);
$.each(json[0], function (i, obj) {
    // obj.FoodName gives us the FoodName string, etc.
    // ... lots of irrelevant code here

    $.each(obj.Description, function (j, t) {
        console.log(t);
    });

    // ... more code here.
});
```

When I use that looping code for the `Description` array, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `json[0]` with `json` !

Comment: Try just `$.each(json, function ...)`. By providing `json[0]`, you're giving `$.each()` the 1st Object for it to iterate keys/values, such as `i === "FoodNumber"` and `obj === "4567421"`.

Comment: why $.each(json[0]...??? instead of $.each(json...???

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks a ton! Please post your answer so I can accept it. =)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Only one object is returned, including all arrays, strings, etc. I've tested this with `console.log();`. Regardless, your proposal and adeneo's worked perfectly.

Comment: @heh If it's only ever one object, you can probably then skip the 1st `$.each()` since you wouldn't necessarily need iteration until `obj.Description`. Just `var obj = json[0];` before that.

Comment: That... is a good point. I modified this code from earlier where I had multiple objects, and I just realized that now. Thanks a ton! *major facepalm*